# Three.js R105 - intersectObjects is not a function, collision worker

Tags: three.js, collision-detection, web-worker

I am looking to perform collision detection in a seperate web worker. I was under the assumption that .intersectObject was a function of the raycaster. However, it appears that it is not?

How would I be able to check for object intersecting in this situation?

```
// Helicopter Collision Detection Web Worker

self.addEventListener("message", function(e){

    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);

    if (data.rayCasters !== undefined) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.collidableMeshList.length; i++) {
            for (let n = 0; n < data.rayCasters.length; n++) {
                console.log(data.rayCasters[n]);
                // data.collidableMeshList[i].updateMatrixWorld()
                const collisionResults = data.rayCasters[n].ray.intersectObjects( data.collidableMeshList[i], true )
                // if ( collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length() ) {
                if ( collisionResults.length > 0 ) {
                    console.log("Collision");
                    self.postMessage(true);
                } else {
                    self.postMessage(false);
                }
            }   
        }

    }

}, false);
```

The error I receive:

```
helicopter-worker.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: data.rayCasters[n].ray.intersectObjects is not a function
```

Comment: `intersectObjects` is a method of [Raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObjects), but you are calling it on `.ray` which is a different thing. [Ray](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Ray)

Comment: Hmmm alright, if I did data.rayCasters[n].intersectObjects I received the same error though.

Comment: Does this problem also happen outside of a worker context? If so, can you demonstrate the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)?

Comment: outside of worker context it appears to not error out... I made a gist that has the excerpts in one file if you are curious. I think I would need to setup a lot to have a live example going. Here is the excerpt: https://gist.github.com/mpaccione/4a37558b0a89595897a82d794498fe51

You can also see the project since I'm making this one public here: https://github.com/mpaccione/everest_flight_sim